# Does data sent through ajax using the POST method have to be URL Encoded before being sent to the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Post data isn't sent as a query string, so would there be any advantage to URL encoding it before sending it?  Or, would one be better off serializing the data, say via Jquery before sending it?

Comment: What's throwing the error?  And what is the error?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, the jquery status/error are too vague.

Comment: Is it returning a 404? is "comment" a PHP script?

Comment: /comment is an app.post() request within express/node.js

Comment: not sure how to check the response header with the ajax request

Comment: Too vague for you, but maybe some of us would recognize.

Comment: Well, is the error visible in your browser's JavaScript console? Or is the returned data an error?  You're alerting the XHR status, so what's the code?  And if you console.log(data), what do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so.

I tried using the same way its work for me.
Could you please mentioned the ajax

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/